# Prometheus : Sending data to the client?

Tags: prometheus

In a system using Prometheus, I'd like to send just a few configuration values to the client.  Does Prometheus have a way to pass parameters to the client?

Comment: In your specific case, what do you mean with "client" ?

Comment: Client here is the system being scraped - providing the data to the server.  This may be a fundamental, obvious feature commonly done.  I'm new to Prometheus trying to understand some of the basics.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to send some properties to the scrape url? `/metrics?property=1`?
Could you please elaborate a bit more on the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, properties to the scrape url may be what I'm looking for.  The server here is collecting data from microcontroller-based sensor systems (clients).  There are occasions where we'd like to command the clients to turn some circuits on or off.  I see Prometheus has many powerful commands for querying the database, but haven't found anything for sending commands to the client.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scrape configuration you can set the `params` property:

```
# Optional HTTP URL parameters.
params:
  [ <string>: [<string>, ...] ]
```

example: `/metrics?property=1`

```
 params:
      property: ['1']
```

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config